# Standard ML: Confusion about Reference Cells

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm reading Harper's Intro to SML and am a bit confused on reference cells.  On p. 114, he gives the following example:

```
val r = ref 0
val s = ref 0
val _ = r := 3
val x = !s + !r
val t = r
val _ = t := 5
val y = !s + !r
val z = !t  !r
```

"After execution of these bindings, x is bound to 3, y is bound to 5, and z is bound to 10."

Here's my trace of his code:

```
val r = ref 0 //allocates storage for r and sets to 0
val s = ref 0 //allocates storage for s and sets to 0
val _ = r := 3 //sets r = 3
val x = !s + !r //sets x = 0 + 3 = 3
val t = r //sets t = 3
val _ = t := 5 //sets t = 5
val y = !s + !r //sets y = 0 + 3 = 3
val z = !t  !r //sets z = 5 + 3 = 8
```

My x is correct (3), but my y and z are both wrong (my y is 3 instead of 5 and my z is 5 instead of 10).

Where am I going wrong here?

Also, why is `val _ = t := 5` necessary instead of simply `t := 5`?

Thanks,
bclayman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`val t = r` does not set `t` to 3. It sets `t` to be the same reference cell that `r` is.

Thus, when you do `t := 5`, you set both the contents of `t` and `r` to 5, since both contain the same reference cell.

As for your other question, `t := 5` is a function call of the function `:= : 'a ref * 'a -> unit`. Thus, `t := 5` is an expression that evaluates to `()`.

`val _ = t := 5` simply throws away the `()` and turns it into a declaration rather than an expression.

Comment: So when I do val t = r, and then t := 5, this somehow changes r also?  That seems very strange...if I changed r to be 5, I would expect t to change to 5 also.  But not vice versa :(

Comment: *Neither* t nor r changes when the expression `t := 5` is evaluated. They both remain references to a specific location in memory. Evaluating that expression has the side effect of altering the contents of that location. Of course r now points to this new value - but not because r itself has been changed. An analogy: If I'm pointing to a dog and you are pointing to the exact same dog, and I tell that dog to "sit" (and it does), you'd be pointing to a sitting dog - but not because I somehow changed you.

Answer (score 4):

`val t = r` makes t an *alias* for r. They both refer to the same location in the store. Thus `t := 5` has the side effect of changing the contents of the memory location that *r* refers to as well (since t and r refer to the same place). Hence

```
val y = !s + !t
```

sets y = 0 + 5 = 5.

You are correct that `val _ = t := 5` is basically the same as `t := 5`, though the former suppresses output in the REPL (by discarding the value of the assignment expression).